# Keep all lines from a file with quotes or curly braces?

Tags: bash, sed

Quick question but was wondering if given an input file, how I could pretty much just keep lines from the file that contain either a `{`, `}`, `"`. What I did was search how to delete all lines that do not contain a certain pattern and ultimately used sed to do something like this:

`sed '/{\|}/!d' news.txt > asd.txt`

This ultimately does only keep lines that contain either a `{` or a `}`, but I have had trouble also adding the whole keeping lines with `"`. I tried doing:

`sed '/{\|/}\}"/!d' news.txt > asd.txt`

but that results in an unmatched `}`.

Any idea on how I could include the `"` to this sed statement?

Thank you!

Comment: `grep -e '{' -e '}' -e '"' news.txt > asd.txt`?

Comment: Yep perfect. Had a feeling grep would be easier to use but couldn't find any relevant ones online. Thanks!

Comment: Shorter version with GNU grep: `grep -E '{|}|"' news.txt > asd.txt`

Comment: shorter shorter version : 

grep '[{}"]' news.txt > asd.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/{\|}\|"/!d' news.txt > asd.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses sed to print only the lines that you want:

```
sed -n '/[{}"]/p' news.txt
```

This does the same with grep:

```
grep '[{}"]' news.txt
```

This does the same but inverts the logic: instead of printing matching lines, it deletes non-matching lines:

```
sed '/[{}"]/!d' news.txt
```

In all cases, `[...]` is used to match any of the characters inside the square brackets.